# Overriding SaveChanges to Implement a Business Rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, objectcontext, savechanges

I created a working solution, which overrides SaveChanges() but would like to know if there is a better, cleaner way to do this. I really don't like the switch statement. Below, I have described the problem and illustrated my full solution.

Thanks

**The problem**
Whenever a user does something that inserts, updates or deletes some of their data, which is spread across multiple tables,
update the column NewClub.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now

**The Models**

```
public  class NewClub
{
 //Primary Key
 public int Id { get; set; }
 [...]
 public DateTime  LastActivityDate { get; set; }
}

 public class NewClubProspect
 {
   //Primary Key
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   //Foreign Key
   public int NewClubId { get; set; }
   [..]
    public virtual NewClub NewClub { get; set; }
}

 public class NewClubCounselor
 {
     [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
     //Foreign Key
     public int NewClubId { get; set; }
    [...]
     public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }
}

// Several more model classes like these ...
```

**The solution**

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var entityInfoStr = String.Empty;
            var saveSuccess = false;
            var newClubPrimaryKeyId = 0;

            ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

            List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList =
            ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added
                                                      | EntityState.Unchanged
                                                      | EntityState.Modified
                                                      | EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
            {
                //Skip over relationships
                if (entry.IsRelationship) continue;

                //Make sure the entity is a member of the schema: NewClub[...]
                if (SecurityHelper.IsValidNewClubTableName(entry.EntitySet.Name))
                {

                    switch (entry.EntitySet.Name)
                    {
                        case "NewClubs":
                            var nc = entry.Entity as NewClub;
                            if (nc != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = nc.Id; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubBuilders":
                            var ncb = entry.Entity as NewClubBuilder;
                            if (ncb != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncb.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubCaseAnswers":
                            var ncca = entry.Entity as NewClubCaseAnswer;
                            if (ncca != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncca.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubCommunityLeaders":
                            var nccl = entry.Entity as NewClubCommunityLeader;
                            if (nccl != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = nccl.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubCounselors":
                            var ncc = entry.Entity as NewClubCounselor;
                            if (ncc != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncc.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubEmails":
                            var nce = entry.Entity as NewClubEmail;
                            if (nce != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = nce.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubKitOrders":
                            var ncko = entry.Entity as NewClubKitOrder;
                            if (ncko != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncko.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubOrganizationChecklists":
                            var ncoc = entry.Entity as NewClubKitOrder;
                            if (ncoc != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncoc.NewClubId; }
                            break;                       

                        case "NewClubProspects":
                            var ncp = entry.Entity as NewClubProspect;
                            if (ncp != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncp.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedules":
                            var ncrts = entry.Entity as NewClubRecruiterTrainingSchedule;
                            if (ncrts != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncrts.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubRecruitingMember":
                            var ncrm = entry.Entity as NewClubRecruitingMember;
                            if (ncrm != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncrm.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubRecruitingTeamEvent":
                            var ncrte = entry.Entity as NewClubRecruitingTeamEvent;
                            if (ncrte != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncrte.NewClubId; }
                            break;

                        case "NewClubSponsor":
                            var ncs = entry.Entity as NewClubSponsor;
                            if (ncs != null) { newClubPrimaryKeyId = ncs.NewClubId; }
                            break;
                    }

                    //Update the NewClub.LastActivityDate column
                    if (newClubPrimaryKeyId > 0)
                    {
                        string q = @"UPDATE NewClub SET LastActivityDate='" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Id="+newClubPrimaryKeyId;


                        using (var context = new MyContext())
                        {
                             var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(q);
                        }


                    }


                }
            }

            try
            {

                 saveSuccess = base.SaveChanges() > 0;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string ex = e.ToString();
                //Handle exception

            }

            return saveSuccess ? 1 : 0; 
        }
}
```

Comment: You may get a good answer here, but if you don't, considering asking this on the code review stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Handle the [ObjectContext.SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for this purpose. It is typically used to validate changed objects before new values are written to the database.

Secondly, define an interface, say `IClub`, with required set of operations, `GetClubId()` in your case. Implement the interface by each entity you need, in a way you need. This will let you check for interface implementation:

```
foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
{
    IClub club = entry.Entity as IClub;
    if (!entry.IsRelationship && club!=null)
    {
          newClubPrimaryKeyId = club.GetClubId();
          ...
    }
}
```

PS. Interface implementation can be done in partial class to your entity, you can also adjust the t4 template if you use database first.

---

Also `ObjectContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` is handy if you are updating multiple entities, in order not to query them all first. In your case you are updating a single item, so you can first query one

```
var club = context.NewClub.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == newClubPrimaryKeyId);
```

and next update it.

```
if (club!=null)
{
    club.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick and concise response. Never worked with these classes before so where do I implement ObjectContext.SavingChanges. Thanks

Comment: it's an event. it is triggered when you call `SaveChanges`. Subscribe to it after you have your context created or within the context constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: btw, you are iterating through modified entities `foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)` and perform operation of updating the `LastActivityDate` each time, do you need that? I think getting first entity of `IClub` interface is what you need: `objectStateEntryList.FirstOrDefaut(entry=>entry is IClub)`, and get the club id from it.